# How to change variable data type on Subclass

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, subclass

I am subclassing say for example UITableView and I want change one of it's variable to suit a protocol delegate of mine.

```
@objc protocol SomeTableViewDelegate: class, UITableViewDelegate {
    /** 
     some documentation here
     */
    optional func didChangeValue(someTableView: SomeTableViewDelegate)

    /** 
     some documentation here
     */
    optional func someDelegateFunction(someTableView: SomeTableViewDelegate)
}

class SomeTableView: UITableView {

    override weak var delegate: SomeTableViewDelegate? // basically this is what I want to do

    var someProperty: Int = 0
}
```

I want to add some implementations to `UITableViewDelegate` but as another protocol and not as UITableViewDelegate since I have some other added properties on `SomeTableView` like `someProperty`

And yes I know that I can just do something like this

```
@objc protocol SomeTableViewDelegate: class {
    ... some functions here
}

class SomeTableView: UITableView {

    override weak var stDelegate: SomeTableViewDelegate?

}
```

Is this possible in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can override it directly. What you could do however, is create an additional property of type `SomeTableViewDelegate`, but of course with a different name. The property could act as a shill and set the delegate property instead. Something like:

```
weak var myTableViewDelegate: SomeTableViewDelegate? {
    get { return self.delegate as? SomeTableViewDelegate }
    set { self.delegate = newValue }
}
```

If you'd want to do this in a cleaner way (i.e.: don't expose 2 delegate properties), perhaps create a custom `UIView` subclass that contains a UITableView. You could then add your own property with the name `delegate` of type `SomeTableViewDelegate` and internally it would cast the type to and from the table view delegate. This way you would not expose 2 delegate properties that both change the delegate property on UITableView.

Comment: The custom subclass that contains a UITableView looks like the best way to do this. Thanks, it didn't occur to me until now, tunnel vision I guess